# How do I load an entity?

Tags: entities

How can I load the entities shown in the following screenshot?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use loadMultiple():

```
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('default_entity');
$config_entities = $storage->loadMultiple();
$list = [];
foreach ($config_entities as $id => $entity) {
  $list[$id] = $entity->label();
}
```